# publish to remote host with merged commits

Tags: git

I want to find a better solution for following situation: We are developing on our own GIT server. The customer now wants us to commit our code also to the customer own GIT server. The project lead on our side has the corresponding credentials and repository. However we do not want to send all commits (in addition with user names, etc.) to a foreign git repository. Instead the project lead should be able to send the merged commits to the customer git repository (each commit on customer git will finally be the sum of individual commits on our side for a given version). By this, we also want to ensure that no personal information from our developers is shared to the customer.

Today, we are exporting the files of our git repository manually, copying it to the "customer directory" and committing the changes to the customer repository. I am quite sure, that this is a quite common use case, but I did't find the "git way" to do that.

Mathias

Comment: One way to handle this would be to only push commits to the customer server from the top level branch you are all committing to. So just specify in your push that you only want to push this single branch. A `squash` can also reduce the number of commits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how come you have *per-user* information in the project? That should not happen. But anyway, coming back to the question. You might consider having a completely different branch for the client.... an *orphan* one, say... let's assume that you start doing this from version v1.0.0 (a tag in your repo).

So, you do something like:

```
git checkout -b --orphan client v1.0.0
# create a revision for the client
git commit -m "Version 1.0.0 for the client"
```

At this point, this first revision in branch client is exactly like 1.0.0 (the real tagged one) but it has no branch relationship to 1.0.0. Now you push this branch into the client's repo.

Then you release 1.1.0..... you tag it. How do we bring it over into the client branch? With a git trick:

```
git checkout v1.1.0 # this is tag, so we are detached from any branch, right?
git reset --soft client # put this on top of client branch
# all differences between the tip of client and what you have on 1.1.0 tag are in index, ready to be commited
# and all will be commited to a single revision after client
git commit -m "Version 1.1.0 for client"
# we need to put client branch over here
git branch -f client
git checkout client
# and now you push into client's repo
```

I would do something like that.